# Dataflow 2.x complaining about incorrect parameter type on call to PCollectionTuple.apply()

Tags: java, apache-beam, dataflow

I'm migrating an existing pipeline to dataflow 2.x. During the final stage of the pipeline, data is written to Google Cloud Services. The data needs to be compressed to .gz, and so previously (in our dataflow 1.x implementation) we had written our own Sink to do this for us. In dataflow 2.x, there is a built-in way to do this. I've got what should be the correct code, but the java compiler is complaining about TextIO.write() returning an incorrect type. The code is as below:

```
PCollectionTuple results = /* some transforms */

// write main result
results.get(mainOutputTag).
apply("WriteProfile", TextIO.write().to(outputBucket)
.withSuffix(".json")        
.withWritableByteChannelFactory(FileBasedSink.CompressionType.GZIP)
.withNumShards(numChunks));
```

Java's compiler is complaining, with this error:

```
The method apply(String, PTransform<? super PCollection<TableRow>,OutputT>) in the type PCollection<TableRow> is not applicable for the arguments (String, TextIO.Write)
```

Does anyone see what the problem might be with my code above? Please let me know if you need more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up resolving the issue. The problem was that I was trying to write a `PCollection<TableRow>` to file, where only a `PCollection<String>` can be written to file.

This was my final solution:

```
PCollectionTuple results = /* some transforms */

// write main result
results.get(mainOutputTag) /* PCollection<TableRow> */

    .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<TableRow, String>() {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            c.output(c.element().toString());
        }
    })) /* PCollection<String> */

    .apply("WriteProfile", TextIO.write().to(outputBucket)
    .withSuffix(".json")        
    .withWritableByteChannelFactory(FileBasedSink.CompressionType.GZIP)
    .withNumShards(numChunks));
```